# while_loop with ValueError Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'while/LoopCond'

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, rank

```
x=([1.,2.],
   [2.,1.])
xtensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
A = xtensor
B = xtensor
def cond(now,pre):
   return (tf.greater(now,pre))
def body(now,pre):
   return pre,now
A,now = tf.while_loop(cond,body,[A,B])
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   A = sess.run(A)
   B = sess.run(B)
   now = sess.run(now)
```

Actually, purpose of the code can be ignored because I simplify the two functions for asking this question and still have the same error:

```
ValueError:Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'while/LoopCond'(op:'LoopCond') with input shapes:[2,2].
```

I'm really confused.....Hope someone can help me.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition function (`cond`) of `tf.while_loop()` must return a boolean tensor of rank 0 (i.e. of shape `[]`, i.e. a single boolean). Your `cond` is returning a boolean tensor of rank 2 (as `tf.greater(now, pre)` returns a tensor of same shape as `now`, performing per-element comparison).

Comment: Oh it really helps. Thank you very much!